# How to use ESI policy to cache logged in user in Magento with Varnish?

Tags: magento, caching, authentication, varnish, esi

I have a Magento site and use Varnish cache to optimize.

I installed and configured PageCache module (a FPC extension for Varnish working with Magento), but when a user logged in, the site couldn't be cached.

The solution is to implement some ESI policies for the module to make it works with logged in user. How can I do that? I need to fix this problem as soon as possible. Thank you so much!